# Need query for somewhat complicated aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I haven't found a way to solve this (in an elegant way), so I'd like to ask for your help with calculating the average week-hours for specific month.

```
declare @person table (pers_id int, [from] date, [to] date, hrs decimal(4, 2));
insert into @person values (72, '2017-09-01', '2017-11-13', 20);
insert into @person values (72, '2017-11-14', null, 35);

declare @months table (ym date);
insert into @months values ('2017-09-01');
insert into @months values ('2017-10-01');
insert into @months values ('2017-11-01');
insert into @months values ('2017-12-01');

/* so I need a query whouch would output average week-hours: */
2017-09-01 = 20
2017-10-01 = 20
2017-11-01 = 28.5
  = (13/30)*20 + (17/30)*35 ; (assumed each month has 30 days) 
2017-12-01 = 35
```

Anybody willing to help me out?
(am on Azure SQL)

Comment: Not sure I understand the data. `(72, '2017-09-01', '2017-11-13', 20)` Does this mean that the person has 20 hours for every week in that time? Or total hours in that time? Every day? Seems arbitrary to have the time end on 11-13 if the 20 hours is per week. What if it ends at half a week?

Comment: Yes, it means hours per week. Full time is 38.5 hours a week. We only change week-hours on Mondays so that should be no problem.

Comment: In the meantime I did come up with a query but it's not always effective since it only works if there is on change of week-hours per person:

`select m.ym, p1.pers_id, IsNull((cast(day(p2.[to]) as float) / 30) * p2.hrs + (cast(31 - day(p3.[from]) as float) / 30) * p3.hrs , p1.hrs)
from @months m
left join @person p1 on m.ym between p1.[from] and IsNull(p1.[to], GetDate())
left join @person p2 on p2.pers_id = p1.pers_id and p2.[to] between m.ym and Dateadd(mm, 1, m.ym)
left join @person p3 on p3.pers_id = p2.pers_id and p3.[from] between m.ym and Dateadd(mm, 1, m.ym)`

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments. You should instead edit your question and add this. The comments are horrible for formatting. I see a number of concerns with the query though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes at most one change in hours per month.  If you have more, then you'd need more complex calculations around the proportions

```
select 
    start,  
    round(sum(

    case 
        when [from]>[start] then (datediff(d,[from],finish)+1) * hrs/days
        when [to]<[finish] then (datediff(d,start,[to])+1) * hrs/days
        else hrs end
    ),2)
from
    (select ym as start, EOMONTH(ym) as finish, 
        30
        --datepart(d, EOMONTH(ym)) 
        as days from @months) months
    inner join (    select pers_id, [from], isnull([to], EOMONTH(getdate()))as[to], hrs from @person) p
        on months.finish>=p.[from] and months.start<=p.[to]
group by start
```

Comment: Hi! This works very well. But I should have written: "assumed each month has MAX 30 days". So February should be calculated with 28|29 days. So I've replaced the "30" in your query with: "IIF(DAY(EOMONTH(ym)) > 30, 30, DAY(EOMONTH(ym)))", seem to be working now. Thanx a lot mate!